I want to create a new query but I get this error "PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant App - assumed 'App' in Psy Shell code on line 1"
I tried
php artisan tinker
then
App\Models\Product::all()
And then I got this error. What could I have done wrong?
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant app - assumed 'app' in Psy Shell code on line 1
thank you in advance for the help

Try will full namespace:
\App\Models\Product::all();

How did I not notice this, thank you bro :)

Please mark it as the correct answer for other people.
